# Inspect Element network tab

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

When inspecting network traffic with inspect element, in the request headers it is only sometimes i can view request headers as raw, Whys that? How can i get RAW request headers very time? Some of you probably gonna answer "copy as curl" or something, though i am only trying to achieve getting the RAW button always showing

[Without RAW button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qHQ5.png)
[With RAW button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHz5W.png)

A solution to my problem